# Unity Firebase Database occasionally doesn't see an authentication success

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I'm using Unity 5.5.3f1, Google Play Services and Firebase Unity SDK with Authentication, Database, and Analytics for a game on Android. I need to authenticate a user via GPS, get a token and use it for Firebase Google-In authentication. Then I use Firebase Database to synchronize player's progress. I'm using following database rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All is going well, but occasionally (mostly in first few attempts) I'm getting "permission denied" error when I try to read or write to the database, although I'm quite sure that user is authenticated and his ID equal to the node which he tries to read or write.
I've tried to add artificial delays (up to 5 seconds), tried to reattempt few times after the first failure but there's still no luck. In order to control authentication and database requests progress, I'm using Coroutines instead of ContinueWith but I think it makes no difference (I've tried ContinueWith also)

There's a small section of code which I'm using now to get a player's playing time from the database:

```js
 public IEnumerator CheckPlayedTime()
        {
            Debug.Log("Database : Start CheckingPlayedTime");
            if (currentUser == null || rootReference == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Database :  Can't get timedPlayedInSeconds! CurrentUser or Reference == null!");
                yield break;
            }

            var task = currentUserNode.Child("fullProgress").Child("timePlayedInSeconds").GetValueAsync();
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted);

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogErrorFormat("Database :  Can't get timedPlayedInSeconds! {0}",
                    task.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (task.Result.Exists)
                {
                    long resultPlayedTime = (long) task.Result.GetValue(false);

                    Debug.Log("Database : Played Time Gotten" + resultPlayedTime);
                    playedTime = (int) resultPlayedTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Database : PlayedTimeNotFound! Will be sent");
                    playedTime = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

There is code section where you can see the sequence of all actions with google play services, firebase authentication, and database. All is running strictly consecutively. Nothing starts until the previous operation has completed. The first method which sometimes throws an error placed above. It's named "CheckPlayedTime".

```js
IEnumerator Start() {
  yield
  return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBetweenOperations); //Искусственная задержка
  GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.Authenticate(); //Делаем попытку авторизации в Google Play Services

  yield
  return new WaitUntil(() => GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.AuthenticationTrialEnded); //Дожидаемся завершения

  if (GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.isAuthorized) //Если авторизация прошла успешно
  {
    yield
    return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBetweenOperations); //Искусственная задержка
    var token = GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.AuthenticationToken; //Получаем токен пользователя
    yield
    return StartCoroutine(FirebaseSystem.instance.Authorize(token)); //Начинаем и дожидаемся окончания авторизации в Firebase

    int playedTime = -1; //Сюда будем записывать сыграное время
    while (playedTime == -1 && attemptsCount < 3) //Повторные попытки получить доступ к данным (если playedTime все еще -1, значит доступ не был получен, пробуем еще)
    {
      yield
      return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBetweenOperations); //Искусственная задержка
      yield
      return StartCoroutine(FirebaseSystem.instance.CheckPlayedTime()); //Начинаем и дожидаемся запроса получения сыгранного времени
      playedTime = FirebaseSystem.instance.playedTime; //Получаем сыгранное время
      attemptsCount++;
    }

    yield
    return StartCoroutine(ProgressSystem.instance.ComparePlayedTime(playedTime)); //Запускаем сравнение времени игры в локальном прогрессе и в базе данных Firebase
    //Если локальное время меньше - запустится загрузка прогресса из базы данных Firebase
    //Если локальнео время больше или не было получено время из базы данных (к примеру его там еще нет) - выполняется отправка прогресса в базу данных
  }

  var loadingOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("MainLoading"); //После завершения всех операций - загружаем сцену главной загрузки игры
}
```

There is Firebase authentication method which runs just between Google Play authentication and first trial of access to database ("CheckPlayedTime"):

```js
public IEnumerator Authorize(string googleIdToken)
        {
            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
            Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, null);

            //Starting of authorization with a gotten user's token
            var task = auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled);
            //Waiting for end of authentication

            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
#if DEBUG
                DebugControlled.Log("AuthMethods : SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
#endif
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
#if DEBUG
                DebugControlled.Log("AuthMethods : SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
#endif
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                currentUser = task.Result;//Getting a current user
                if (rootReference != null)//And a his own node in database
                    currentUserNode = rootReference.Child("users").Child(currentUser.UserId);

#if DEBUG
                DebugControlled.Log(string.Format("AuthMethods : User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    currentUser.DisplayName, currentUser.UserId));
#endif
            }
        }
```

Again - it's working well, but not always. Every time I'm getting a correct token for authorization, completing firebase authorization, and getting proper user ID. But sometimes, right after it, the database just doesn't give an access to itself, but the user is definitely authenticated properly and should have an access. I'm so puzzled and don't understand how it's possible. Does anyone know what's going on here?...

Answer (score 0):

Firebase developer here.  We found that if the Database component is used before Auth, the Database component wasn't seeing auth token updates.  So even if sign-in succeeded the Database component would still not be authenticated.

We've applied a fix which is available in the 4.2.0 release of the Firebase Unity SDK.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.2.0

Cheers,
Stewart